# Implement hierarchy with PagedCollectionView

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I am trying to implement DataGrid, in Silverlight, which should organize data like this:

Group 1
    Subgroup 1.1
         Subgroup 1.1.1
                 Domain 1.1.1.1
         Subgroup 1.1.2
                Domain 1.1.2.1
Group 2
      Subgroup 2.1
          Domain 2.1.1

Group and Subgroup are actually one table with self-reference. The main question would be, is it possible to implement self-reference hierarchy using grouping with PagedCollectionView?

Any other idea would be also good. The point is that I want to implement hierarchy like this using Silverlight DataGrid, and without adding another grid inside grid.

Joksimovic

Comment: Why you don't use `TreeView`?

Comment: The previous version was implemented using TreeView. But, leaf not should contain more than just one label. And TreeView with GridView as a leaf, was really bad solution...